# Missing a Regex concept for matching (search lookahead)

Tags: python, regex

I want to match "python":

```
re.match("python", "python programming") # --> True
```

I want to exclude the chance of something other than whitespace after "python", so I thought:

```
re.match("python[^ ]", "python3 programming")  # --> False
```

The problem is that I would still like to match if it would be just "python":

```
re.match("python[^ ]", "python")               # --> False   (Should be True)
```

Making it optional does not work, since then it would match the previous case while that should return false:

```
re.match("python[^ ]?", "python3 programming") # --> True  (Should be False)
re.match("python[^ ]?", "python")              # --> True
```

Similar situation for "programming python", where "python" should also be matched.

What is the concept here that I am missing so that all matches are correct?

Comment: Would you want to match `"python!"`?

Comment: No, only "python", optional spaces around it, optionally at the beginning of the string and optionally at the end of the string

Comment: Well, then @alexce's solution is not correct for you because it *will* match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
>>> re.search(r"python(?!\S)", "python3 programming")
>>> re.search(r"python(?!\S)", "python")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000298E370>
>>> re.search(r"python(?!\S)", "python ")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000298E3D8>
>>> re.search(r"python(?!\S)", "python!")
>>>
```

`(?!\S)` means "Make sure that it is not possible to match a character other than whitespace after the current position of the regex engine". This is true if either a whitespace character or nothing follows the current position.

Comment: The first shouldn't match by the way?

Comment: @Dualinity: I got your requirements backwards. Does it work correctly now?

Comment: The only thing, and it sucks I can't figure it out by now, how to match also "programming python"?

Comment: @Dualinity: You need to use `re.search()`, not `re.match()`. The latter forces the match to start at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Excellent. Phew. What is the `r` doing in front of the string by the way?

Comment: Sorry, it really has been insightful answer, but specifically for this topic alex has the most elegant solution. +1

Comment: @Dualinity: The `r` makes the string a "raw string" where backslashes are treated as literals. `"\b"` means "backspace", `r"\b"` means "backslash, followed by `b`", which to the regex engine means "word boundary".

Comment: This is a good point. Which other characters fail this test, and why?

Comment: Yea, my bad. Your answer for sure is the correct one. `"python."` is also matched.

Comment: `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

Comment: One more thing. How do you make the word "python" a variable? So that you can go over a list and use "django" instead?  `re.search(r + var + "(?!\S)", "django.")` does not work, where `var` is "django"?

Comment: @Dualinity: That should be `re.search(var + r"(?!\S)", "django")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for word boundaries `\b`:

```
>>> re.search(r"\bpython\b", "python programming") 
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb72be5d0>
>>> print re.search(r"\bpython\b", "python3") 
None
>>> re.search(r"\bpython\b", "programming python") 
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb72be5d0>
```

Comment: That's not the same, though. `"Python!"` would match too, even though `!` is not a space.

Comment: @TimPietzcker the OP wants just "python" word as far as I understood.

Comment: What about "programming python"?

Comment: @Dualinity just use `re.search`. `re.match` goes from the beginning of the string.

Comment: I think this is the proper way to do it.

Comment: Why does this not match: `re.search(r"a" + "a" + "\b", "aa")`?

Comment: @Dualinity `\b` should be raw: `r"\b"`.

Answer (score 0):

you could add the special case explicitly:

`(python[^ ])|(python$)`

Answer (score 0):

With `[^ ]` you're actually excluding whitespace, not everything else. Also, to ensure you're done you should include the end string symbol. Both combined give you:

```
python( |$)
```